# putenv in php, is it uniq every time the php is called

Tags: php

I am using `putenv` to pass a variable to a shell script from PHP.
(this is the only way I managed to do it)

PHP receives the IP from a HTML form:

```
$ip=$_POST["ip"];
```

then i put the value in an environment variable:

```
putenv("ip=$ip");
```

In the Shell script I have:

```
ip=$IP
```

So in this way I can use this variable in the shell script.

My question is if this PHP is going to be called multiple times(with different IP values on the HTML form), maybe even at the same time, will the `putenv("ip=$port")` contain the correct value or will it overwrite the previous one.

I just don’t understand if this `putenv` will define some kind on global variable that will be overwritten every time the php is run.

Comment: php spawns one process, starting from the request and once the response is sent, it dies. The env variables will be set only be set for the scope of each php process. It looks weird to me what you are trying to do (setting env variables from user-generated content); what is your goal?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a shell script and pass env vars to it, the best way to do this might be, just to pass the env vars directly in the execution.

```
$ip = $_POST['IP'];
echo `IP=$ip script.sh`;
```

If you are new to php, have a look at the [backtick operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php), which executes scripts.